# Promotion through Gaming.SE - ideas needed

Tags: discussion, status-declined, promotion

Gaming.SE has a Community Promotion Ads contest that might be interesting for us: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012

The short version is: Post a small picture with a link, get votes by the community and if it is popular enough it gets an featured ad space on the (highly frequented) Gaming.SE site.

---

Because many gamers also have an affinity for movies and series, this might be a great chance to promote our beta. The idea is not completely new, philosophy.SE beta already posted a proposal. Due to the topical proximity between movies and games we might have a better shot than them though.

All we need is a short catchy sentence, a fitting image and we are good to go.

---

So lets get our creativity flowing and come up with a good submission to the program.

**If you have a good idea for an ad, post it here and we can vote on which one we want to submit.**

To illustrate what the ads could look like, here are some entries others already submitted:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Discussion in the comments please.

Comment: The community ads, from my small understanding, are ads that get posted on that parent site only initially. On mobile atm but as soon as i learn more/have an idea regardless, i shall elaborate

Comment: Community ads are designed to promote things that are relevant for that community, not other communities ;-)